# Xcode: Random label generator no repeat?

Tags: xcode, label, generator, repeat

I am creating an app that has a random label generator, but I'm finding that its repeating sometimes. And I was wondering if I can take this problem right out, but I'm not sure how to? Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've provided my .h and .m files.
Here's my .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MessageUI/MessageUI.h"
#import "Social/Social.h"
#import "Accounts/Accounts.h"
#import <iAd/iAd.h>


@interface ViewController2 : UIViewController <MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate,    ADBannerViewDelegate> {
SLComposeViewController *mySLComposerSheet;
//label that is being randomly generated.
IBOutlet UILabel *label;

}

-(IBAction)randomButton;
-(IBAction)randomButton2;
-(IBAction)SendSMS:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)PostToFacebook:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)SendATweet:(id)sender;

@end
```

Here's my .m

```
-(IBAction)randomButton {
int randomText = rand() %151;
switch (randomText) {
    case 0:
        label.text = @"1";
        break;
    case 1:
        label.text = @"2";
        break;
    case 2:
        label.text = @"3";
        break;
    case 3:
        label.text = @"4";
        break;
    case 4:
        label.text = @"5";
        break;
    case 5:
        label.text = @"6";
        break;
    case 6:
        label.text = @"7";
        break;
    case 7:
        label.text = @"";
        break;
    case 8:
        label.text = @"8";
        break;
    case 9:
        label.text = @"9";
        break;
    case 10:
        label.text = @"10";
        break;
    case 11:
        label.text = @"11";
    //ect.....
```

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your random number will repeat at point of time, but you can store them and check. one all the number till 150 is filled, reset and start again.

You can do something like this:

```
-(IBAction)randomButton {
    NSInteger random=arc4random()%151;
    if ([self.randomNumbers containsObject:@(randomNumbers)]) {
        [self randomButton];
    }
    else{
        [self.randomNumbers addObject:@(random)];
    }
    label.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",random+1];
}
```

Here, `randomNumbers` is a property of type NSMutableArray. While reset make it empty.

Comment: Thanks for the help, much appreciated! How would I implement this to my already code? Thanks so much!

Comment: replace entirely with this. And there may be some mistake...plz bear

Comment: Thanks, I was also wondering for a different project, that for my .m file, can I scan a .txt file and then make it random, in stead of having all these cases?

Comment: Explain your question. What u do after reading the entire file? what randomly u wnat to pick?

Comment: I want to be able to put strings into a txt file, and then scan it for the strings and randomly select